# Loading different modal based on knockout.js value

Tags: html, knockout.js, bootstrap-modal

[image]

So I have a table of people's information and I used codes that look something like below (people's location in this case):

```
  <!-- ko foreach: filteredApplications -->
     <div class="col-md-6">

        <span>Location:</span>

        <span data-bind="text: application.candidateLocation"></span>

     </div>
```

to display location information for all people.

And when I click the "Preview Application" link, it is supposed to give me a modal like the attached image and show the information of the corresponding person.

I tried to remove the foreach knockout for the modal, but then it gives me an error saying that it cannot find the application.candidateLocation variable.

How do I have to approach this issue?

Please help!

EDIT (viewmodel):

```
public partial class Application
    {
     public dynamic JsonForm => new
     {

        CandidateLocation,
        Job = this.Job.JsonForm,
        CandidateStatus = this.CurrentStatuse.CandidateStatus,

    };

    public string CandidateLocation
    {
        get
        {
            switch (ApplicationCandidateType)
            {
                case ApplicationCandidateType.Standard:
                    return InsideApplication.CandidateApplication.Candidate.Location;
                case ApplicationCandidateType.Guest:
                    return null; 
                case ApplicationCandidateType.Manual:
                    return null; 
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Unhandled ApplicationCandidateType");
            }
        }
    }

 function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.invite = ko.observable(false);

        self.changeStylesInvite = function () {
            self.invite(true);
        }

        self.notifications = ko.observableArray(@Html.Json(Model.Notifications.Select(o => o.JsonForm)) || []);

        self.applications = ko.observableArray(@Html.Json(Model.ApplicationCompatibilities.Select(o => o.JsonForm)) || []);
        self.applicationInvitations = ko.observableArray(@Html.Json(Model.ApplicationInvitations.Select(o => o.JsonForm)) || []);

        self.applicationsFilter = ko.observable("new");
        self.showHiddenApplications = ko.observable(false);

        self.newApplicationsCount = ko.computed(function() {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.applications(), function(i) {
                return !i.application.isShortlisted && !i.application.isContactInfoSent && (self.showHiddenApplications() || !i.application.isHidden);
            }).length;
        });
        self.shortlistedApplicationsCount = ko.computed(function() {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.applications(), function(i) {
                return i.application.isShortlisted && (self.showHiddenApplications() || !i.application.isHidden);
            }).length;
        });
        self.connectedApplicationsCount = ko.computed(function() {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.applications(), function(i) {
                return i.application.isContactInfoSent && (self.showHiddenApplications() || !i.application.isHidden);
            }).length;
        });
        self.allApplicationsCount = ko.computed(function() {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.applications(), function(i) {
                return (self.showHiddenApplications() || !i.application.isHidden);
            }).length;
        });
```

Comment: Does your view-model have an application property? Does that application property contain an object which has a candidateLocation property?. It would help if you show your view-model.

Comment: @JasonSpake Looks something like the edit. Thanks!

Comment: I meant your javascript view-model. The object or class that the knockout data-binds are pointing to.

Comment: @JasonSpake Will that work?

Comment: That's on the right track, but I don't see a "filteredApplications" property, or an "application" property. Where are those coming from?